# How to programatically set Windows Phone's 7 keyboard to UPPER CASE?

Tags: windows-phone-7, text, uppercase

I can do it manually, but how can I set this from my code, so when I give focus to a textbox the keyboard will allow the user to start typing in UPPER CASE?

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* you force it to be all upper case, but is doing a .ToUpper() on the value they type in a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

This way is even better:

```
private void codeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tPCodeText.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text.ToString().ToUpper();
    tPCodeText.SelectionStart++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TextChanged event.

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Save cursor's position
    int cursorLocation = textBox1.SelectionStart;

   // Uppercase text
   textBox.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();

   // Restore cursor's position
   textBox.SelectionStart = cursorLocation;
}
```

[source](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/64199.aspx)

Comment: Thank you lukas, that works! What I was after is to get the same behaviour as in native apps, where you move focus to a textbox and the keyboard pops up with CAPS ON, and after typing in the first letter, it goes back to CAPS OFF. I should have explained better. I have found that playing with InputScope and InputScopeNames does the trick. The name in particular I was looking for is InputScopeNameValue.PersonalFullName.